# Solving Angle of a triangle using Vectors

Tags: vectors

In the isosceles triangle $ABC$ , $|\vec{AB}|$ = $|\vec{BC}|$ =$8$ , a point E divides AB internally in the ratio 1:3, then the cosine of the angle between $|\vec{CE}|$ & $|\vec{CA}|$ is ( where $|\vec{CA}|$ = $12$ ) ?

If i do this question by normal geometry it is going very complicated and long, can anyone help me to do this by concepts of vectors ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the angles A,B and C by cosine rule. 
Say req. angle is $X$.
Now $$\frac{\Delta BCE}{\Delta ACE}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot BE\cdot h}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot AE\cdot h}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3AE\cdot h}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot AE\cdot h}=3$$ or, $$\frac{\Delta BCE}{\Delta ACE}=3$$ or, $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot BC\cdot CE \cdot \sin(C-X)}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot AC\cdot CE \cdot \sin(X)}=3$$ or, $$\frac{\sin C\cos X-\sin X\cos C}{\sin X}=3 \times 12 /8=\frac{9}{2}$$ or, $$\sin C\tan X-\cos C=\frac{9}{2}$$

From here you can find X by plugging in C.